# Latex: How to add to the generated PDF file a variable URL from a text file?

Tags: file, url, latex

I have a text file called "data.txt" which contains an URL.

The problem: `\url(\input{data.txt}}` doesn't add the link to the PDF.

I've tried:

```
\url{\input{data.txt}}

\url{\string \input{data.txt}}

\newcommand{\newCommandName}{\input{data.txt}}
    \url{\newCommandName{}}

\newcommand{\newCommandName}{\input{data.txt}}
    \url{\string \newCommandName{}}
```

I don't understand why the code

```
"\input{data.txt}"
```

Is translated perfectly from the text file to the generated PDF by Latex, but why is

```
"\url{\input{data.txt}}"
```

returning me an error?

I need to get the URL from the text file - and since that URL is generated by another program first, I can't just copy it into Latex manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there us a file `test.txt` that only contains

```
https://stackoverflow.com
```

then one can use the little trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203507/36296 :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{document}

test

\CatchFileDef\urlfile{test.txt}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
\url{\urlfile}

\end{document}
```

[image]